# 100 Projects in Python - Reverse String alternate answer

Tags: python, python-2.7

Just finished Learn Python the Hard Way and I'm now working on the GitHub 100 Projects for Python.

Let me start by saying that I do understand this is the solution to the reverse a string project:

```
string = raw_input("> ") 
print "< %r" % string[::-1]
```

**Example:** 'Hello string' >>> 'gnirts olleH'

The above program reverses the string from back to front, but what I would like is a reversal in place, so I made this (Which does what I want it to do):

```
myString = raw_input("> ")

running = True

while running:
    myList = myString.split(' ')
    myList.reverse()
    myNewString = ' '.join(myList)
    print myNewString
    running = False
```

**Example:** 'Hello string' >>> 'olleH gnirts"

I am a brutal perfectionist and I am curious if someone knows of an even better way to acheive the same using a For-loop rather than a while-loop? Am I overlooking something obvious? Thank you!

**EDIT:** I do understand that the while loop here does nothing, thanks for feedback!

Comment: Your while loop does literally nothing here. It executes only once. There is also nothing 'in-place' about this (reversing a string in-place is not possible in Python - strings are immutable).

Comment: You don't need a loop at all, nor do you need to use a list. `myNewString = myString[::-1]` would achieve the *exact same thing*.

Comment: Python strings are immutable, you can reassign the string though.

Comment: Please read the question more throughly - I did acheive my in-place reversal by converting my string to a list, reversing the list, and then converting back to a string.

I do understand now that the while-loop does nothing here though, thanks.

Comment: That's not in-place reversal. You bind the variable to a new string.

Comment: @HarrisonBoles - what, precisely, do *you* mean by "in-place reversal"?

Comment: @Robᵩ Apparently OP means, "reverse each word and maintain the word order".

Comment: Look at his example: He wants each word's letters to be reversed, but the words to remain in the same order.

Comment: @HarrisonBoles The confusion here arises from your usage of "in-place". This term refers generally to operations that work on a data structure without cloning it, and has nothing to do with word boundaries.

Comment: The confusion also arises because your code doesn't do what you claim it does. It will print `string Hello`. For a perfectionist, you've overlooked a lot of details. :-)

Comment: Sorry I did not realize that in-place was another term, I was just trying to be descriptive. 

@alexis - I don't know what you mean, my code does perform the task sucessfully I just tested.

Comment: Your code will not convert `'Hello string'` into `'olleH gnirts'`. What did you test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one with a for loop

```
s = 'Hello World'
rev = []
for i in s.split(' '):
    rev.append(i[::-1])

print ' '.join(rev)
```

Answer (score 1):

Mayeb something like this:

```
>>> def reverse(s): return ' '.join (s[::-1] for s in s.split(' '))
... 
>>> print (reverse('Hello World!'))
olleH !dlroW
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it seems to me the easiest to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

The elegant way to manipulate your string is with a generator and `' '.join()`:

```
>>> myString = "Hello world!"
>>> print ' '.join( s[::-1] for s in myString.split() )
olleH !dlrow
```

And since you mentioned `while`: When you *do* need an endless loop, it's more idiomatic to do it like this:

```
while True: 
    ...

    if exit_condition(): 
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining your answer, I apperciate it.\

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear in your post on how you would want to handle multiple white space between words. For example, `'Goodbye cruel\t\tWorld!'` has two tabs. Is the correct result `eybdooG leurc !dlroW` or `eybdooG leurc\t\t!dlroW`?

If it is the later, which is what the 'perfectionist' in ME says is correct, here is a 'for' loop method with a regex:

```
import re
st='Goodbye cruel\t\tWorld!'

li=[]
for e in (m.group(1) for m in re.finditer(r'(\S+|\s+)', st)):
    if e.strip():
        e=e[::-1]
    li.append(e)        

print '{}=>{}'.format(st, ''.join(li))   
# Goodbye cruel     World!=>eybdooG leurc       !dlroW
```